# Filter results through two values in the same column if one is multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to list customers who have purchased from ProductCategoryKey 1, and if those customers have purchased ProductCategoryKEY 3 **more than once** show only one row for that customer. My code so far only filters through PC Key 1. How can I say 'of those who have purchased PC Key 1, how many have purchased PC Key 3 at least two times and only show that person once?'

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.FirstName, C.LastName, PC.EnglishProductCategoryName
FROM dbo.FactInternetSales AS I
INNER JOIN dbo.DimCustomer AS C
    ON I.CustomerKey = C.CustomerKey
INNER JOIN dbo.DimProduct AS P
    ON I.ProductKey = P.ProductKey
INNER JOIN dbo.DimProductSubcategory AS SC
    ON P.ProductSubcategoryKey = SC.ProductSubcategoryKey
INNER JOIN dbo.DimProductCategory as PC
    ON SC.ProductCategoryKey = PC.ProductCategoryKey
WHERE PC.ProductCategoryKey = 1
ORDER BY C.LastName ASC, FirstName ASC;
```

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2019
ADventureWorksDW2017

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output in text format.

Comment: Break your problem into pieces - that usually leads you to a solution. You have the first piece (presumably). What query would you use to find rows for the "more than once" condition? Seems like count and a having clause would do that.

Comment: The thing that's throwing me off would potentially being an IF function since I want to show Key 1 customers that may not be Key 3 customers.

Comment: @SkyBennett as already requested, please provide some sample data and expected results (as formatted text **not** images) to clarify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using temp tables, or variable tables, as a way to further filter data.  The first query gets all customers with a PC Key of 1 and 3, and inserts those records into a temp table.  Then, the second query uses aggregation and a `GROUP BY` clause to count all rows where the PC Key is 3, followed by a `HAVING` clause where the count is > 2.  The `GROUP BY` clause in the second query effectively creates a distinct record-set for your last requirement.

I break up the query into two queries for readability. You could also use nested sub queries to achieve the same result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.FirstName, C.LastName, PC.EnglishProductCategoryName, 
    PC.ProductCategoryKey
into #temp1
FROM  dbo.FactInternetSales AS I
INNER JOIN dbo.DimCustomer AS C
    ON I.CustomerKey = C.CustomerKey
INNER JOIN dbo.DimProduct AS P
    ON I.ProductKey = P.ProductKey
INNER JOIN dbo.DimProductSubcategory AS SC
    ON P.ProductSubcategoryKey = SC.ProductSubcategoryKey
INNER JOIN dbo.DimProductCategory as PC
    ON SC.ProductCategoryKey = PC.ProductCategoryKey
WHERE PC.ProductCategoryKey = 1
    AND PC.ProductCategoryKey = 3
ORDER BY C.LastName ASC, FirstName ASC

SELECT  FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductCategoryName, COUNT(*)
FROM    #temp1
WHERE   ProductCategoryKey = 3
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductCategoryName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: Does this take into account the IF? We need to show those with Key 1 even if they don't have Key 3. I really like the temp table idea.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want all customers with Key 1, and all customers that have Key 1 and have 2 or more Key 3?  Sounds confusing.  If you want all of Key 1, and all of Key 3 for 2 or more, wouldn't that just be all of Key 1?

Comment: Yes. You're right. It ends up being the same by just using DISTINCT. It was worded like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CTE over a temp table unless you have a performance issue. This way you get a single execution plan which is often better (except when its not) than splitting into two execution plans (as using a temp table does).

Also you shouldn't need a `distinct` unless you have your logic wrong. A correctly grouped query very rarely needs a `distinct`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, PC.EnglishProductCategoryName, PC.ProductCategoryKey
    FROM  dbo.FactInternetSales AS I
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimCustomer AS C ON I.CustomerKey = C.CustomerKey
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimProduct AS P ON I.ProductKey = P.ProductKey
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimProductSubcategory AS SC ON P.ProductSubcategoryKey = SC.ProductSubcategoryKey
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimProductCategory AS PC ON SC.ProductCategoryKey = PC.ProductCategoryKey
    WHERE PC.ProductCategoryKey = 1 AND PC.ProductCategoryKey = 3
)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductCategoryName, COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE ProductCategoryKey = 3
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, EnglishProductCategoryName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC;
```

I am assuming the logic is correct, because without sample data and expected results its hard to know.

Comment: Can this be altered with an IF to list both Key 1 customers who may or may not be Key 3 customers?